# Javascript Regex? Or other method to veryfi correct text input

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use input text on webpage to build a SQL Query (Where clause).

We have some 'predefined' queries with numbers - and i would like to give user possibility to write something like:

```
[1] AND [2]
[1] OR [2] AND NOT [3]
[1] OR NOT ([2] AND [3])
etc.
```

Is it possible to verify by js regex? Or any other method? I would like to give to user only possibility to write numbers in brackets, brackets, and words OR, AND and NOT. Nice would be checking if brackets are OK - but the most important thing is creating only allowed characters.

Answer (score 1):

Validation of the correct nesting of brackets is only possible if you can limit the nesting depth, but even then it's going to be complicated. And syntactic correctness (disallowing something like `"[1] OR AND AND"`) is going to be even more difficult.
For those problems, you'd actually need a parser.

You *can* use a regex to easily check that input contains nothing but the allowed characters/words/patterns:

```
/^(?:\[\d+\]|\b(?:AND|OR|NOT)\b|[ ()])*$/
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wN3lM9/1).

Comment: Thanks, work great! It will be enought for my needs.